# Puppet creates same package on every run on Windows agent

Tags: windows, windows-installer, ms-office, puppet

I use following code to install MS Office 2013 Proofing tools with Puppet. To target computers have Windows 7 as their OS and their language is English. Puppet server runs on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
 package {'Microsoft Officen tarkistustyökalut 2013 - suomi':
                    ensure          => '15.0.xxx...',
                    source          => '\\source\proofingtools_fi-fi-x86.exe',
                    install_options => [ '/quiet' ],
                    require => Package['Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013'],
            }
```

If package is not installed on target all goes well. After it is installed on every Puppet run I get:

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/Officeinstaller/Package[Microsoft Officen tarkistustyökalut 20
13 - suomi]/ensure: created
```

This slows down the Puppet run by about 10 seconds. Its not much but still annoying.

Proofing tools get installed correctly and work.
Changing *ensure =>* to *present* or *installed* does not solve problem.
The Package name is written exactly as it appears in Windows Add or Remove Programs. 
Other programs (including MS Office 2013) don't have this problem when installed with similar code.

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Could you be looking at character encoding issues?

Comment: Could be that. But I have about 20 other programs on Puppet and only this is giving me problems. How could I test for encoding problems?

Answer (score 0):

I would open an admin command prompt and type `puppet resource package > c:\SomewhereICanFindThis\packages.txt`
In the text file find your resource for the proofing tools. That is exactly what Puppet sees installed, so if you copy it out and paste it into your resource it should stop trying to reinstall it as the resource name should match.

Answer (score -1):

You could try adding:
    replace => no,
to your package stanza.

Comment: Gives: ERROR 400: Invalid parameter